# setting "Modal" at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog

C# WinApp:  if I am creating a form at run time How can I tell it to be "Modal" ...
I tried mFrmPersons.Modal = true  but compile error was saying it is a read only property. so what can I do?  Thanks

EDIT: I cannot use Show or Show Dialog! I have a form that some other application is embedding inside it. so the only way I can call my form is like this:

```
moPersons.NonClinDocDialog.ShowDocs(DocContext);
```

The only thing I have control over it is `moPersons` that is the form I am defining in my Application... rest of it a call to other apps...so I want to set the Modal for moPersons

Comment: forgot to mention that in the question: I cannot use Show or Show Dialog! I have a form that some other application is embedding inside it. so the only way I can call my form is like this: moPersons.NonClinDocDialog.ShowDocs(DocContext);  so the only thing I have control over it is moPersons that is the form I am defining in my Application... rest of it a call to other apps...so I want to set the Modal for moPersons

Comment: You could edit the question to reflect this :)

Comment: You can only simulate a modal dialog if you can get an event when the form is closing (not closed).

Comment: I'd try to fake it... Perhaps show another form in the loading etc

Answer (score 2):

Using `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()` might work.

Comment: yes forgot to mention that in the question: I cannot use Show or Show Dialog! I have a form that some other application is embedding inside it. so the only way I can call my form is like this: moPersons.NonClinDocDialog.ShowDocs(DocContext);  so the only thing I have control over it is moPersons that is the form I am defining in my Application... rest of it a call to other apps...so I want to set the Modal for moPersons

Answer (score 1):

The trick is deciding whether the code shows the form with `theForm.Show()` vs `theForm.ShowDialog()` - so it is the code that displays the form that needs tweaking.

Comment: yes forgot to mention that in the question: I cannot use Show or Show Dialog! I have a form that some other application is embedding inside it. so the only way I can call my form is like this: moPersons.NonClinDocDialog.ShowDocs(DocContext);  so the only thing I have control over it is moPersons that is the form I am defining in my Application... rest of it a call to other apps...so I want to set the Modal for moPersons